# How can I call a Sails.js controller's function from another function of the same controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Given the following Sails.js controller, how can I call its `processLogin` method from its `processRegistration` method?

Currently this results in a `ReferenceError: AuthController is not defined` on line 56 (`AuthController.processLogin(req, res);`).

If I change it to `this.processLogin(req, res);` I get a `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'processLogin'`.

Similarly if I change it to just `processLogin(req, res);` I get `ReferenceError: processLogin is not defined`.

```
/**
 * AuthController.js 
 *
 * @description ::
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/controllers
 */

 var passport = require('passport');

 module.exports = {
  login: function (req, res) {
    res.view('auth/login');
  },

  processLogin: function (req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
      if ((err) || (!user)) {
        res.redirect('/login');
        return;
      }
      req.logIn(user, function (err) {
        if (err) res.redirect('/login');
        console.log(user);
        console.log('user ' + user.username + ' logged in');
        return res.redirect('/user');
      });
    })(req, res);
  },

  logout: function (req, res) {
    var username = req.user.username;
    req.logout();
    console.log('user ' + username + ' logged out');
    res.redirect('/login');
  },

  register: function(req,res) {
    res.view('auth/register');
  },

  processRegistration: function(req, res) {
    var userObj = {
      username: req.param('username'),
      password: req.param('password')
    };

    User.create(userObj, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.redirect('/register');
      }

      console.log('user ' + user.username + ' registered');

      // Log user in
      AuthController.processLogin(req, res); // ReferenceError here

    });
  },

  _config: {}
};
```

I am using Sails.js `0.10.0-rc5`.

Comment: try module.exports.processLogin

Comment: I think I got it (see my answer). That works too though. Thanks!

Comment: no problem. hoisting takes some getting used to. it's odd to think that you can reference an outer variable that, at first glance, hasn't been fully instantiated yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactoring slightly fixed it:

```
/**
 * AuthController.js
 *
 * @description ::
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/controllers
 */

var passport = require('passport');

var AuthController = {
  login: function(req, res) {
    res.view('auth/login');
  },

  processLogin: function(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if ((err) || (!user)) {
        res.redirect('/login');
        return;
      }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) res.redirect('/login');
        console.log('user ' + user.username + ' logged in');
        return res.redirect('/user');
      });
    })(req, res);
  },

  logout: function(req, res) {
    var username = req.user.username;
    req.logout();
    console.log('user ' + username + ' logged out');
    res.redirect('/login');
  },

  register: function(req, res) {
    res.view('auth/register');
  },

  processRegistration: function(req, res) {
    var userObj = {
      username: req.param('username'),
      password: req.param('password')
    };

    User.create(userObj, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.redirect('/register');
      }

      console.log('user ' + user.username + ' registered');

      // Log user in
      AuthController.processLogin(req, res);

    });
  }
};

module.exports = AuthController;
```

I had tried this previously but just didn't get the `module.exports` line right (did something like `module.exports = { AuthController: AuthController };`, which didn't work either).

Comment: How do you call it in the route then

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but `sails.controllers.` exposes the controllers